# Weird moving pixels on both monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, pixels

I recently had my laptop repaired and a few days after receiving it back, I noticed these weird moving pixels on my screen. They started of quite unnoticeable but a few months down the track and they are getting worse. They appear on both monitors (I have removed external monitors) so I am assuming it isn't anything to do with the display. Also, they disappear after around 5 hours of having my laptop turned on.

Whenever something happens on the display (ie: select box on desktop, window open), they move.  View the image below full size to see the pixels (might require right-click menu).

I don't really want to send it back as it took 3 months to repair last time (laptop wouldn't turn on) and I need it for work and study.

Here is a video (not mine) of what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2mfr9psGs0

[image]

Comment: corruption of video frame buffer memory

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: lower the temp, either by fixing the cooling system, or manipulating the video memory clock or display device clock lower

Comment: Why would this affect it when it turns on then? I live in a cold climate area so it's not like it's going to be 100 degrees on start up.

Comment: climate means nothing if there is no way to get the heat out. temperatures on a chip can get to the boiling point of water in seconds, and yes it can effect boot. extended high temperatures can also warp the traces on the PCB, and damage the connections to the chipa